# How to use iOS7.1 to compile my project in xcode6?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have downloaded iOS simulator&SDK 7.1:
[image]

but int he build settings, I could not choose iOS7.1 as my Base SDK:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don to run on a simulator you have to make sure your Deployment Target is set to >= 7.0

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode 6, your base SDK of the project will always remain 8.1.You can never change that.
You can only set the deployment target in Project>General settings.
For base SDK to be 7.1 use Xcode 5

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build with the iOS7 SDK using Xcode 6. Are you trying to change your app's iOS SDK version, or are you just trying to run on the iOS7 simulator?